# Call two functions from same onclick

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

**HTML & JS**

How do I call 2 functions from one onclick event? 
Here's my code

```
 <input id ="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="pay() cls()"/>
```

the two functions being pay() and cls(). 
Thanks!

Comment: Hello semicolon, dear statement terminator. `pay(); cls()`

Comment: What's inside your quotes is just javascript. Separate java statements using a semicolon. ie: `pay(); cls();`

Answer (score 278, accepted):

Add semi-colons `;` to the end of the function calls in order for them both to work.

```
 <input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="pay(); cls();"/>
```

I don't believe the last one is *required* but hey, might as well add it in for good measure.

Here is a good reference from SitePoint http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/event-attributes/onclick

Answer (score 55):

You can create a single function that calls both of those, and then use it in the event.

```
function myFunction(){
    pay();
    cls();
}
```

And then, for the button:

```
<input id="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="myFunction();"/>
```

Comment: it can be done, but seems to me  it is not so transparent or it could be named similar to something like funtion1_function2(), in a case that funcitons are not related.

Comment: won't it have more overhead than just doing onclick="pay(); cls();" ?

Comment: @Am33d an overload that translates as one cell in the stack and half a millisecond extra for processing. It is more than worth it for the gain in readability and easy of maintenance. Imagine that in the future you have to add three extra methods, with conditional logic.

Answer (score 21):

You can call the functions from inside another function

```
<input id ="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="todo()"/>

function todo(){
pay(); cls();
}
```

Comment: It's been more than a year since this answer, and only now I noticed we posted the same answer at almost the same time (but you beat me by a minute, so have my +1).

Answer (score 14):

```
onclick="pay(); cls();"
```

however, if you're using a return statement in "pay" function the execution will stop and "cls" won't execute,

a workaround to this:

```
onclick="var temp = function1();function2(); return temp;"
```

Answer (score 12):

Binding events from html is NOT recommended. This is recommended way:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    pay();
    cls();
});
```

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery :

```
jQuery("#btn").on("click",function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    pay();
    cls();
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Just to offer some variety, the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) can be used too but some might say "noooooo!", but it works:

```
<input type="button" onclick="one(), two(), three(), four()"/>
```

http://jsbin.com/oqizir/1/edit

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
<input id ="btn" type="button" value="click" onclick="pay();cls()"/>
```

Answer (score 6):

put a semicolon between the two functions as statement terminator.