# Run 2 Function on button click...?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
 <button id="take-photo"> Take Image</button> 
 <button type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit </button>
```

How to run two task on single button click 
1. Calling function with ID 
Next 
2.Submit the form with the hidden input value

Below is my effort  however it runs only 1 function

```html
<button id="take-photo"  type="submit" value="Submit"  >Click me To fire some functions</button>
```

Comment: hrm... looks to run zero functions to me...

Comment: Before asking question try to search first on google or stack overflow. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025138/call-two-functions-from-same-onclick)

Comment: Call two functions in that one function which the button calls. Or separate the function calls with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Just put 2 function after `onclick`

```
<button onclick="f(); g();" id="take-photo"  type="submit" value="Submit"  >Click me To fire some functions</button>
```

Comment: Seems Function word has created the confusion __I want to call the function with ID and then submit the form  input value

Currently, I am using Tow Buttons

<button id="take-photo"> Take Image</button>
<button type="submit" value="Submit"  >Submit </button>
looking an option to mergre with one Button

Comment: If you merge two button to one and call two function, functions will be called same time. If you have to call one function after another, you have to separate those. Otherwise just put a button and call two. Pass parameter