# How to set multiple function for same button using onClick?

Tags: javascript

Is it okay to use it twice like this:

```
onClick=function1() onClick=function2()
```

?

Comment: No. The second `onClick()` will override the first one and only `function2()` will be called when your item is clicked.

Comment: Use `addEventListener` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event) and [Call two functions from same onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025138)

Comment: @thatguy `onClick=function1() onClick=function2()` in this case, `function1` will be called. `function2` won't be called.

Comment: Have you tried googling the title of your question?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `addEventListener`.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('yourButton');
button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  // call function 1 here
  // call function 2 here
  console.log('test');
});
```

```html
<button id="yourButton">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No. If you want to call both functions in one on click you would need to do something like

```js
function clicked(){
   function1();
   function2();
}

function function1(){
  console.log('function1');
}

function function2(){
  console.log('function2');
}
```

```html
<button id="yourButton" onClick='clicked()'>Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the one commented to you, the second will override the first.

What you need to do is to call foo() and inside foo call the two functions you need:

```
function foo() {
   func1();
   func2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). It gives you the flexibility later on to remove the added listener by calling [removeEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)