# Calling two functions and a html page with onclick event at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to call two functions and a html page at the same time using onclick event in javascript only
This is what i tried..but its not working!!

```
 <button type="button">
        <a href = "example.html"
        onclick="return check();
        check2();">Login </a>
</button>
```

Comment: basiclly you just have to remove the `return` but it will go to first function and when finish go to secont and not in the same time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call multiple JavaScript functions in onclick event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910736/how-to-call-multiple-javascript-functions-in-onclick-event) and [Call two functions from same onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025138)

Comment: Have you tried googling the title of your question before posting here? There are so many duplicates. Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="main_check()">Login</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
function main_check() {
    check();
    check2();
    window.location = 'example.html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place anchor outside button:

```
<a href="link.html" onclick="check(); check2();">
        <button>Login</button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a wrapper function and call the two functions there and after that you redirect to other page

```
<button type="button">
        <a href="#"
        onclick="wrapperFunction()">Login </a>
</button>

function wrapperFunction() {
   check();
   check2();
   window.location.href = 'example.html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single function and inside that function call `check` & `check1` , SInce you want to execute `href` , return `true` from the `onclick` event handler

```js
function check() {
  console.log('check')
}

function check2() {
  console.log('check2')

}

function singleFnc(e) {
  check();
  check2();
  return true;
}
```

```html
<button type="button"><a href = "http://www.google.com"
            onclick="singleFnc(event)">Login </a>
    </button>
```

Comment: This has several duplicates and you have javascript gold badge. Why would you answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one warp function contain two function call.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the onclick attribute and go straight to addEventListener. Along with allowing as many functions as you want, this technique lets you separate the concerns of structure (in HTML) and logic (in javascript).

```
<button id="myButton">Click me</button>
<script>
  const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");
  myButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ check(); });
  myButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ check2(); });
</script>
```

Comment: (Edited to fix a syntax error)

Comment: where do we place the webpage link then ?

Comment: You can redirect the browser to the desired page inside any function. So if you define a variable called `myHref` that holds the value `example.html`, you can include it in your function expression like: `function check(){ window.location.href = myHref; }` (Note that if you wanted an absolute url, your variable's value would look more like `https://example.com`).

Answer (score 0):

You can call two functions like below and return the value of the function as below:

```js
function check() {
/* Your code */
console.log("Check");
/* return the value */
return false;
}
function check2() {
/* Your code */
console.log("Check 2");
}
```

```html
 <button type="button">
        <a href="example.html"
        onclick="return (function(){var ret = check(); check2(); return ret;})();">Login </a>
</button>
```