# call multiple function with one button javascript

Tags: javascript, button

i'd like to know if its possible to call several function with one html button?

```
<button onclick:"functions()">Calls</button>
```

So could anyone try to explain to me if it is possible and how and maybe show me through some code snippets or anything.

Comment: You can all one function from the button and inside the called function call other functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call two functions from same onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025138/call-two-functions-from-same-onclick) — first result when searching _“js call multiple functions on button click”_. Is there a specific problem you’re having with some _attempt_ that you’re not showing us?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, like so:
This is the best option because you attach the event handler to the DOM node with javascript see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)

html:

```
<button id="calls">Calls</button>
```

javascript:

```
document.getElementsById('calls').addEventListener('click', function(){
    function1();
    function2()
})
function function1() {
    //whatever you want which will be called first by the button
}
function function2() {
    //whatever you want which will be called second by the button
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('calls').addEventListener('click', function(){
    function1();
    function2()
})
function function1() {
    console.log("function1 was called first")
}
function function2() {
    console.log("function2 was called second")
}
```

```html
<button id="calls">Calls</button>
```

or so:

html:

```
<button onclick="function1();function2();">Calls</button>
```

javascript:

```
function function1() {
    //whatever you want which will be called first by the button
}
function function2() {
    //whatever you want which will be called second by the button
}
```

```js
function function1() {
    console.log("function1 was called first")
}
function function2() {
    console.log("function2 was called second")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="function1();function2();">Calls</button>
```

or so:

html:

```
<button onclick="functions()">Calls</button>
```

javascript:

```
function functions() {
    function1();
    function2();
}
function function1() {
    //whatever you want which will be called first by the button
}
function function2() {
    //whatever you want which will be called second by the button
}
```

```js
function functions() {
    function1();
    function2();
}
function function1() {
    console.log("function1 was called first")
}
function function2() {
    console.log("function2 was called second")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="functions()">Calls</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, **you're better off not using `onclick` at all and attaching the event handler to the DOM node through your Javascript code.** This is known as [Unobtrusive_JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

In order to bind multiple functions to one button, you can either do this (But it is **not preferred** at all):

```js
function fn(){
  console.log('fn is called!');
}

function fn2(){
  console.log('fn2 is called!');
}

function fn3(){
  console.log('fn3 is called!');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="fn(); fn2(); fn3();">Calls</button>
```

Or bind your function with `addEventListener` like this (This is the most **preferred approach** for calling multiple functions):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(){
  fn();
  fn2();
  fn3();
})

function fn() {
  console.log('fn is called!');
}

function fn2() {
  console.log('fn2 is called!');
}

function fn3() {
  console.log('fn3 is called!');
}
```

```html
<button>Calls</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do that:

```
<button onclick="function1();function2()">Calls</button>
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute multiple function by order

```js
function f1()
{
  alert("execution of f1");
}
function f2()
{
  alert("execution of f2");
}
function f3()
{
  alert("execution  of f3");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="f1();f2();f3();">Click Me</button>
```